# Django logging with dynamic name

Tags: python, django, error-logging

I'm trying to create logs in my django project, but i want a log with a different filename for each execution. What i did so far is set it up like it's written [here](http://ianalexandr.com/blog/getting-started-with-django-logging-in-5-minutes.html), but this creates one log and puts everything in it. I want a log per execution with a dynamic name, like instance name + date or something. Can this be done?

Edit: Code example of creating a scheduled task. (I think you will get what it does from this)

```
def create_schedule (inst):


     path_task=os.path.join(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),os.pardir),os.pardir)
     path_task=path_task[:len(path_task)-2]+'executeInstance.py'
     tr='"py '+path_task + ' ' + str(inst.id)+'"'
     tn='Inst ' + str(inst.id)

     time=inst.schedule.time


     if inst.schedule.scheduleType=='Weekly':

        w_days=''
        for day in inst.schedule.weekDays.all():
                if w_days!='':
                   w_days=w_days+','
                w_days=w_days+day.weekDay[:3].upper()

        tn='"'+tn+'"'
        cmd_sch='schtasks /create /tn ' + tn + ' /tr ' + tr + ' /sc weekly /d '+ w_days + ' /st ' + time + ' /RU SYSTEM'
        result = subprocess.check_output(cmd_sch, shell=True)
```

And then catching an exception in executeInstance.py

```
    except smtplib.SMTPDataError as e:

            status_log='Error'
            error_desc='Message size too big for your email server'


            inst=Instance.objects.get(id=instance_id)
            log=Log(instance=inst,status=status_log,errorDesc=error_desc,executionDate=datetime.now())
            log.save()
            logger.error(log)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "per execution"?

Comment: My program is creating some taks for the task scheduler. So every task has his own id, name etc. So if i schedule Task 1 to be executed today at 13h, and tomorrow at 13h, i would like to have 2 logs. "Taks1-20-01-2016".log and "Task1-21-01-2016".log. Even if i could have just different log for every task would be fine. Like Task1.log,Task2.log etc.

Comment: Please add code example

Comment: I edited the original question with an example of what the app does, and example of catching an error and logging it.

Comment: FileHandler may not be the handler that you actually need to use, you may want either to try the `MailHandler` so you get individual emails you can do something with or something like sentry/opbeat/appenlight

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to play with time rotated log files? https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/logging.handlers.html#rotatingfilehandler

Comment: With this i get stuck on the same thing as with filehandler. Since handlers are in settings.py, I can't get the instance execution time there. (Or maybe i just don't know how) If i could get this time agrument there, then i could also get the inst.name and use this as a filename, and solve the problem. Don't know am I right or not, still new at this. If you have any suggestions how to get instance execution time/instance name in settings.py please share.

Comment: i thought that if you know that you execute task every hour/day (for example), then you can set the time accordingly. If this is not the case, then indeed, it is not very helpful.